# How to pass a calculated variable to another activity in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to calculate the total in the mainActivity and pass it to the second Activity using explicit intent,
i tried this way but id doesn't work, i want to know how to pass the calculated total to the secondActivity
and this is the code:

```
        TextView result_total_Last; 
        public void calculateTotal(View view) {
        EditText number = findViewById(R.id.number_user);
        int num = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());
        String result_total;
        if (radio_days.isChecked()) {
            result_total = (""+ (num * 50) );
        } else {
            result_total = (""+ (num * 1000) );
        }
        result_total_Last.setText("the total is" + result_total);
    }

// and this is the on click method that used to pass to second activity

  book_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (ValidateEmailAddress(email)) {

                    //create intent to pass the values//
                  
                    String result_intent = result_total_Last.getText().toString();


                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Confirmation_interface.class);
                     
                    intent.putExtra("total", result_intent);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }

        });


//code of second activity 

        Intent intent = getIntent();
 
        String total = intent.getStringExtra("total");
 
        TextView Total_result = findViewById(R.id.Total_ET);
 
        Total_result.setText(total);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the error? show the log

Answer (score 0):

Try receiving like this

```
 String total = getIntent().getExtras().getString("total","defaultIfNotPassed");
```

Comment: is doesn't work, Is there any way to pass a textview content to the second activity ? because the calculated total is textview in the MainActivity

Comment: This is the way, you are doing something else wrong. Move your getting data to onClick listener